# Vertical Align Center not working for div text alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I am trying to vertically align and I can not find the solution. I have read so many stack overflow questions and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is my HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <form class="order-form">
                <div class="row first-row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 v-middle">
                        <span>Order 123456789</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 v-middle">
                        <span>Order Date: 8/28/18</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 v-middle">
                        <span>Order Status: OP</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 v-middle">
                        <span>Ready Status: RD</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 v-middle">
                        <span>Facility 123 Dudley Chip-N-Saw</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

and here is my SCSS:

```
$font-family: "roboto", "open-sans";
body {
font-family: $font-family;
padding-top: 5%;
.order-form {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    label {
        display: block;
    }
    .first-row {
        font-size: 16px;
        .v-middle {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }           
    }
}
}
```

I a using Bootstrap v3 so I can not use the alignment classes Bootstrap 4 provides. I am not sure what else is required for vertical align besides display being inline. I know vertical alignments do not work on block level items. Please help Thanks!

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/sazad/pen/BOZWOV

but Please shrink screen to make sure when the line breaks the text is vertically aligned middle. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.v-middle` elements inherit float from the `col-..` elements, thats why you can't vertically align them. Simply add `float: none` to that class to fix it.

You will also have a problem with whitespaces in-between `display: inline-block` elements. A lot of ways to fix those, my favourite fix for those is adding `font-size: 0` to parent.

Final code:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <form class="order-form">
                <div class="row first-row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 v-middle">
                        <span>Order 123456789</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 v-middle">
                        <span>Order Date: 8/28/18</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 v-middle">
                        <span>Order Status: OP</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 v-middle">
                        <span>Ready Status: RD</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 v-middle">
                        <span>Facility 123 Dudley Chip-N-Saw</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

$font-family: "roboto", "open-sans";
body {
    font-family: $font-family;
    padding-top: 5%;
    .order-form {
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        label {
            display: block;
        }
        .first-row {
            font-size: 0;
            .v-middle {
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: middle;
                float: none;
                font-size: 16px;
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Also a small suggestion. Don't nest selectors that heavily (for ex. `order-form` doesn't need to be nested inside `body`).